# XML/XSL compression using maven

Tags: java, xml, xslt, maven, compression

I have used YUI maven plugin to compress css and js when building war file. But couldn't find a plugin to do XML/XSL compression. Can anyone suggest a way to do this? It has to be done when the war file is built through maven. Even a script which can be included with maven
for this purpose will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML and XSL are DATA, best you can do is eliminate whitespace, not compress the same way you would compress JavaScript but changing 'var someVariableIneed' to 'var x'. I don't think its really going to save you much if you can even find something for this (extraneous) task.

Comment: Actually i'm looking forward to remove all the comments in XML/XSL files which goes to production by this compression. So looking for a script or plugin to do this....

Comment: Can't you just execute a simple regex in that case to match and remove any comments?

Comment: Greg, I'm  unable to get a clear picture on how to do it with maven. Can you please provide me an example to eliminate whitespace and comments from xsl files through regex which can be executed through maven?

Comment: Why do you need to do with Maven , Just make a version for deployment and point Maven to that . To Manipulate XML I would recommend Groovy XML Slurper. Do not forget to vote for my comment ;)

Comment: Thanks Shahzeb, i did it with a groovy script... :)